# Integration over non-orientable Riemannian manifolds

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have been reading *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis* by Jürgen Jost. He uses integration over Riemannian manifolds (without boundary) which are not assumed to be orientable. While I know that there are many ways to define a natural notion of integration on such manifolds, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730834/measure-on-non-oriented-riemannian-manifold) (the author seems to be using the fourth definition mentioned there), I need several things to hold for this situation:

1. I need some form of Stokes' theorem. At least I need the fact that the Laplacian is self-adjoint, and also Green's identities.
2. I need Sobolev spaces over such manifolds. In particular, I need the Sobolev embedding theorem and the Rellich–Kondrachov theorem.

Are these actually correct in the non-orientable situation? And what is a reference for such matters?

Comment: Do you know the book: Emmanuel Hebey Nonlinear analysis on manifolds: Sobolev spaces and inequalities ?

Comment: @VictorHugo Yes. Does that book contain textbook treatments of these matters?

Comment: When it comes to Sobolev spaces over manifolds, many consider it as a classic. The Taylor's book, Partial Differential Equations volumes 1 (page 281), also have a treatment about Sobolev spaces on compact manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

If you lift up to the orientable double cover all this follows.

If you can't use that, you still know $M-\operatorname{Cut}(p)$ is diffeomorphic to a ball, so you can appeal to results on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for that.

Comment: Thanks. So exactly what results hold? Does the original Stokes theorem hold in this setting?